# Convert string into dictionary with python

Tags: python, parsing, converters, python-2.5

I know that this question sound a duplicate, but it's not, at least looked for a while and I couldn't fine nothing for my specific problem.

I have the following string:

```
"{first : {name : 'test', value : 100}, second : {name : 'test2', value : 50}}"
```

And I want to convert that string to a dictionary something like this:

```
{'first': {'name': 'test', 'value' : 100}, 'second': {'name': 'test2', 'value' : 50}}
```

Any ideas? I'm working with Python 2.5

Thanks

Comment: First, where did you get the string from? It's very close to what you'd get from either `repr(d)` or `json.dumps(d)`, and if you're actually generating these strings, you could change your code to generate it one of those ways, and then things would be easy.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Except that question has a string that's already in valid format, and the answer requires Python 2.6. So it's related, but not a duplicate.

Comment: @abarnert: ah, missed the python 2.5 requirement there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think the missing quotes are a more serious problem. Even if 2.5 had `literal_eval` (and, as I pointed out in my answer, you can work around that relatively easily), it would just throw a `ValueError` on the OP's string.

Comment: @abarnet: Thanks for the typo, there was a missing brace on the first string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes, the missing quotes are the real issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, if you're generating these strings from dictionaries (in Python or almost any other language), you might want to consider generating them in a way that can be easily parse. For example, in Python. either `repr(d)` or `json.dumps(d)` will give you something very similar to your existing string, but with proper quotes.

---

But if you've just got a mess of strings someone else gave you, the easiest thing to do might be to regex it into an actual JSON string so you can parse it:

```
json.loads(re.sub(r",\s*(\w+)", r", '\1'", 
                  re.sub(r"\s*\{\s*(\w+)", r"{'\1'", x)).replace("'", '"'))
```

In 2.5, there's no built-in `json` module, so you probably want to `pip install simplejson` and then you can do this:

```
try:
  import json
except ImportError:
  import simplejson as json
```

(Or, of course, you can just require `simplejson` unconditionally, if you prefer.)

---

A different alternative is to use `ast.literal_eval` instead of `json.loads`. Which one is appropriate depends on more information about your strings. JSON is more restricted than Python syntax, so it's safer if you're worried about the source of your input, but not as flexible if your input might legitimately have stuff that JSON can't handle, like `1+3j`.

However, like `json`, `ast` is new to 2.6, and there's no drop-in replacement available on PyPI. Fortunately, 2.5 *does* have the `_ast` module, and you can just copy and paste the source `literal_eval` from 2.6's `ast.py`, but this is a bit of a hassle. There are also recipes at ActiveState, such as http://code.activestate.com/recipes/364469/ that, while not identical to `literal_eval`, may be right for your purposes.

This still won't quite work, because you're also missing the closing right brace in the example string. I'm hoping that's a typo, in which case there's not a problem.

If not, you need to explain what you want it to actually do with such cases. Maybe auto-close any unclosed braces? If so, could unclosed brackets also be a problem?

Comment: I think the `json` module was also not introduced until 2.6, more's the pity.

Comment: @abarnert  small nit pick in the regular expression - which misses the leading spaces before the first key. Here's a small update (Note: I actually faced this problem while working with a string) `re.sub(r",\s*(\w+)", r", '\1'", re.sub(r"\s*\{\s*(\w+)", r"{'\1'", x)).replace("'", '"')`

Comment: @gabhijit: Thanks! Updated the answer to include your correction.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com), which is backward-compatible to Python 2.5 - see comments in annotated code below:

```
from pyparsing import Suppress, Forward, Word, nums, quotedString, removeQuotes, alphas, alphanums, Group, delimitedList

# define some punctuation expressions
LBRACE,RBRACE,COLON = map(Suppress,"{}:")

# forward declare dict_, because we will use it as part of defining
# dict_value, which we will then use to define dict_ (i.e., the grammar
# is recursive)
dict_ = Forward()

# what does a key value look like (guessing it is any word that
# starts with an alpha or '_', followed by zero or more alphas, nums, or '_'s)
dict_key = Word(alphas+'_',alphanums+'_')

# define possible values for dict entries (expand as needed)
# parse actions do data conversion during parsing, so that we get native Python types,
# not just strings for everything that we have to convert later
integer = Word(nums).setParseAction(lambda t:int(t[0]))
quotedString.setParseAction(removeQuotes)
dict_value = quotedString | integer | dict_

# a dict element is key : value
dict_element = Group(dict_key + COLON + dict_value)

# use a parse action to convert parsed data to dicts while parsing
make_dict = lambda t: dict(t.asList())

# finally, define dict_ using '<<' operator to "inject" the pattern into the previously
# defined Forward - delimitedList(expr) is a short-cut for expr + ZeroOrMore(',' + expr)
dict_ << (LBRACE + (delimitedList(dict_element).setParseAction(make_dict) + RBRACE))

# parse the input string - we get back a real dict, not just a hierarchical list of strings
data = "{first : {name : 'test', value : 100}, second : {name : 'test2', value : 50}}"
dd = dict_.parseString(data)[0]
print type(dd)
print dd
print dd.keys()
print dd['first'].keys()
```

prints:

```
<type 'dict'>
{'second': {'name': 'test2', 'value': 50}, 'first': {'name': 'test', 'value': 100}}
['second', 'first']
['name', 'value']
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but I choose the json option because it's more straight forward.

Comment: +1. It's defiintely worth learning how to write a simple parser, because you will run into cases where it's not so easy to transform the input into something you already have a parser for…